# How can I conditionally subset numpy array from the bottom only?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array and would like to remove several rows from the bottom that meet certain conditions.

```
import numpy as np

A = [[1906, 0, 50.00, 0.00, 11.01, 0.00],
 1906, 1, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
 1906, 2, 72.00, 0.18, 13.41, 0.00],
 1906, 3, 23.00, 0.29, 20.89, 0.00],
 1906, 4, 52.00, 0.39, 28.36, 0.00],
 1906, 5, 88.00, 0.49, 35.84, 0.00],
 1906, 6, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
 1906, 7, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
 1906, 8, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
 1906, 9, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]]

B = A[np.logical_not(np.logical_and(A[:,2] == 0, A[:,3] == 0))]
```

Using slices and subsets as above removes all rows that meet the condition. However, I would like to retain any row that occurs anywhere else but towards the end, the second row for example.

The array A will not be a fixed shape (i.e. more or less rows possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1906, 0, 50.00, 0.00, 11.01, 0.00],
    [1906, 1, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
    [1906, 2, 72.00, 0.18, 13.41, 0.00],
    [1906, 3, 23.00, 0.29, 20.89, 0.00],
    [1906, 4, 52.00, 0.39, 28.36, 0.00],
    [1906, 5, 88.00, 0.49, 35.84, 0.00],
    [1906, 6, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
    [1906, 7, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
    [1906, 8, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
    [1906, 9, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]],dtype=int)

B = A[np.logical_not(np.logical_and(A[:,2] == 0, A[:,3] == 0))]
```

## Option

```
n = np.where(np.sum(A[:,2:],axis=1) >0)[0][-1]
B = A[:n]
```

Comment: I think that should read n = 4. However, the problem is the same as above: I need a method to evaluate n in advance.

Comment: I've updated the code to dynamically figure out n. Since it seems your actual data starts from the 2nd to the last column (?), the sum across these columns should be zero, indicating bad data. To find n, you need to find the last occurrence of a nonzero, this will skip through zeros that occur earlier on  in your data (such as row 1.